# Linq - distinct with a field must return all fields

Tags: c#, linq

Im working on a file that contains so many line with same package and also there are so many different packages on this file. I want to select different ones

column1 Model column3 column4 ... column12 -> all of these columns are content of my package (InformationFields)

I want to get distinct values of packages with using Model column. (if Model in information fields of this line is changed , this is a new package)

Im new on Linq, learning and wrote below line that returns me `List<string>` that contains different model names in my file. But i want to have `List<InformationFields>`.

```
distinctPackages.AddRange(packages.Select(x => x.InformationFields.Model)
                                  .Distinct().ToList());
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are projecting packages into strings. That's why you have string list at the end. In order to have `InformationFields` you need grouping by model. Then you can select first package from each group and project it to `InformationFields`:

```
distinctPackages.AddRange(packages.GroupBy(p => p.InformationFields.Model)
                                  .Select(g => g.First().InformatioFields));
```

Comment: How tha f*** did you understand that from what he wrote? :P

Comment: @flindeberg from error he has :) He selects distinct values of  string property, but he wants whole distinct InformationFields objects)

Comment: @lazyberezovsky, Dash it! I focused on distinct, not dream of grouping. (S)he thanks to you for answer and understanding :)

Answer (score 2):

you can use [Distinct with equality comparer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb338049%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) something like this

```
class PackagesEqualityComparer : IEqualityComparer<PackagesType>
{
    public bool Equals(PackagesType x, PackagesType y)
    {
        return x.InformationFields.Model == y.InformationFields.Model;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(PackagesType obj)
    {
        return obj.InformationFields.Model.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

and use like this

```
distinctPackages.AddRange(packages.Distinct(new PackagesEqualityComparer()).ToList());
```